# Hide label class in div

Tags: php, label, osclass

For 2 days I didn't understand why my pictures aren't uploaded onto my server correctly.

I am using *osclass* and in my theme I have this :

```
<?php if( osc_price_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="price"><?php _e('Recompensa', 'infinity'); ?></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php ItemForm::price_input_text(); ?>
            <?php ItemForm::currency_select(); ?> ( optional )
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I was partially able to achieve what I wanted: when someone chooses a category where the price is off, the label with text price disappears, but I still have the problem that my pictures don't upload.

This was my code, but with this the text PRICE is not disappearing, only the text area is:

```
<?php if( osc_price_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="price"><?php _e('Price', 'bender'); ?></label>
        <p class="controls">
            <?php ItemForm::price_input_text(); ?>
            <?php ItemForm::currency_select(); ?> ( optional )
        </div></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your second code block.  You open a P rather than a DIV.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to adjust this , was my mistake , the last  from my code was in addition i deleted and now is ok , my server uploads pictures with no problem , thank you all

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
<p class="controls">
```

should be

```
<div class="controls">
```

Unless there is something I'm missing.